# Solr Search sort by score in solr1.2

Tags: php, symfony, solr

One of my project use solr1.2 and when i use "sort by score" in search function it's not working.I don't know why?

Can any one explain this.I am totally confuse.

my controller where i do :

```
protected function globalSearch($searchTerm, $productFilter = array())
{
    $solrService = $this->get('syd.solr_service');

    $solrQuery = new SolrQuery('*:*');
    $solrQuery->addField('id')
        ->addField('first_product_slug')
        ->addField('first_product_name')
        ->addField('name')
        ->addField('slug')
        ->addField('thumbnail_path')
        ->addField('product_slug')
        ->addField('design_category_id')
        ->addSortField('score', SolrQuery::ORDER_DESC);
    $solrQuery->set("group", "true"); 
    $solrQuery->set("group.field", "first_product_id"); 
    $solrQuery->set("group.limit", 4); 

    if($searchTerm){
        $filterQueries = array();
        $searchTerms = explode(' ',$searchTerm);
        $searchTerms[] = $searchTerm;
        $searchTerm = '("' . implode('" OR "', $searchTerms) . '")';
        $filterQuery = sprintf(self::SEARCH_STRING, $searchTerm);
        $solrQuery->addFilterQuery($filterQuery);
    }

    if (!empty($productFilter))
    {
        $productFiltersArr = array();
        $productFilterQry = '';
        foreach ($productFilter as $productFilterValue )
        {
            $productFiltersArr[] = 'first_product_slug:' . $productFilterValue;
        }
        $productFilterQry = implode(' OR ', $productFiltersArr);
        $solrQuery->addFilterQuery($productFilterQry);
    }

    $solrQuery->setRows(1000);
    try {
        $solrObject = $solrService->query(
            'SydPrintBundle:DesignTemplate',
            $solrQuery,
            SolrService::WRITER_FORMAT_SOLR_OBJECT
        );
        $templates = $solrObject->offsetGet('grouped')->offsetGet('first_product_id')->offsetGet('groups');
    } 
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $templates = array();
    }

    if (!$templates) {

        if (!empty($searchTerm)) {
            $this->setFlash('catalog-message', 'No results found for your search.');
        }

        return array();
    }
    if (!$searchTerm) {

        if (!empty($searchTerm)) {
            $this->setFlash('catalog-message', 'No results found for your search.');
        }

        return array();
    }

    return $templates;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `when i use "sort by score" in search function it's not working` I assume you are telling that the results are not sorted by score.

This is because your main query is `*:*` and you are adding your search terms via a filter query, which won't influence the score. See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq where it says

`This parameter can be used to specify a query that can be used to restrict the super set of documents that can be returned, without influencing score.`

So if you make the search term filter query as your main query, then you should see results sorted by score.

**Update:**
Instead of

`$solrQuery = new SolrQuery('*:*');`

use

`$solrQuery = new SolrQuery();`

and instead of

`$solrQuery->addFilterQuery($filterQuery);`

use

`$solrQuery->setQuery($filterQuery);`

Comment: Can you explain How i make the search term filter query as my main query?